# Sort an array of words by the last letter

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of words by their last character.

```
def array_sort_by_last_letter_of_word(array)
  list = array[-1,1]
  list.sort { |a,b| b <=> a }
end

puts array_sort_by_last_letter_of_word ['sky', 'puma', 'maker']
```

The output I get is just `"maker"`.

Comment: Please, make sure to select and accept the answer that solves your issue best. This way you let the community know that your problem is solved and also you reward effort of those, who spent time helping you.

Answer (score 6):

```
def array_sort_by_last_letter_of_word(array)
  array.sort_by { |word| word[-1] }
end
```

Rails version (using [String#`last`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/last)):

```
def array_sort_by_last_letter_of_word(array)
  array.sort_by(&:last)
end
```

Comment: AltBrian, in case you ever do this in Rails, you can use `word.last`:). @Andrey do you think we'll ever get `String#first`,`String#last` in plain Ruby?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 can't say, but don't see any reason not to get it there sometime :)

Comment: Although not called for by the question, and depending on how the result is to be used, `array.sort_by { |word| [word[-1], word] }` may be more useful, as it alphabetizes words having the same last letter.

Answer (score 1):

Andrey's answer is definitely the way to do this. But to understand what's going wrong with your code:

```
list = array[-1,1]
```

This syntax is for getting a subarray of an array. The pattern is `array[start, length]` to get an array starting at index `start` with length `length`. So you are asking for an array starting at `-1` (which means the last index) of length `1` i.e. just the last element of the array. So `last = ['maker']`. That's why your sort method is just returning that element.

You want to get the last character *inside* the sort block, which is what determines how strings are compared

```
array.sort { |a,b| a[-1] <=> b[-1] }
```

Also note that `a` needs to be left of `b`, otherwise the array is sorted in reverse.

Comment: Also note that while `sort` is more versatile than `sort_by`, in majority of cases `sort_by` suffices, and is much, much faster than `sort`.